# SQLite and android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android and I am creating an app that stores students info. I am not able to validate login using SQLITE. When I run the below code it directs me to the login page but I get the error "Unfortunately yourapp has stopped".

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    final EditText txt_usn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usn);     
    final EditText txt_psw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
       public void loginListener(View v){
           DBAdapter db= new DBAdapter(getBaseContext());
           db.open();   
           db.InsertData("1cr11is004", "rai123");
           Cursor cur = db.fetchStudent( txt_usn.getText().toString() , txt_psw.getText().toString());
           System.out.println("cur.getCount()   "+cur.getCount());
           if(cur.getCount()!=0)
            {
                String usn=cur.getString(1);
                if(usn.equals("1cr11is004"))
                {   }else{  }
                System.out.println("Query succedded");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success! Valid USN and password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                db.close();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter Valid USN and password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

And below is the DBAdapter.java

```
public class DBAdapter {
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student_Info";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_STUDENTS = "create table Students (ID integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "USN varchar, Password varchar);"; 
        private static final String DATABASE_SELECT_STUDENTS="students";
        public static final String Student_ID = "ID";
        public static final String Student_USN = "USN";
        public static final String Student_PASSWORD = "Password ";
        private final Context context;
        private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase db;

        public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
        {
            this.context = ctx;
            DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }
        private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
        {
            DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
            {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }

            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
            {
                System.out.println("Creating table");

                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_STUDENTS);
                //I commented this line after my initial run since    
                //I wanted to add users using SQLite Browser and the 
                //table need only be created once. 
            }

            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                //empty method

            }
        }   
        public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
        {
            db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }
        public void close() 
        {
            DBHelper.close();
        }
        public Cursor fetchStudent(String usn, String password) 
        {  
               Cursor myCursor = db.query(DATABASE_SELECT_STUDENTS,   
                          new String[] { Student_ID, Student_USN, Student_PASSWORD },   
                         Student_USN + "='" + usn + "' AND " +   
                         Student_PASSWORD + "='" + password + "'", null, null, null, null);  

               if (myCursor != null) {  
                    myCursor.moveToFirst();  
               }  
               return myCursor;  
          }  
        public void InsertData(String usn, String password)
        {
            String sql="INSERT INTO students (USN,Password) VALUES('"+usn+"','"+password+"')";
            db.execSQL(sql);
        }


}


This Is The Error shown by logcat

04-18 02:04:33.010: W/dalvikvm(757): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  ... 11 more
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at com.abhineel.studentinfo.LoginActivity.loginListener(LoginActivity.java:39)
04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  ... 14 more
04-18 02:04:33.250: W/ActivityManager(163):   Force finishing activity com.abhineel.studentinfo/.LoginActivity
04-18 02:04:33.310: W/WindowManager(163): Failure taking screenshot for (164x246) to layer 21015
04-18 02:04:33.850: W/ActivityManager(163): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4132cda8 com.abhineel.studentinfo/.LoginActivity}
```

Comment: If there's a crash, there's exception stacktrace in logcat. Include it in your question. Also please pay attention to code formatting to make it readable.

Comment: am new to stackoverflow.com . I am posting the logcat error and i'll surely keep "Formatting the code properly" when posting next time. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 04-18 02:04:33.110: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at com.abhineel.studentinfo.LoginActivity.loginListener(LoginActivity.java:39)

The LogCat states there is an null reference exception at line 39 in the method `loginListener`

You need to look there.